# SQL command to using SUM() with the Where clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please I am typing from my phone as I am not with the laptop,  don't decrease my reputation.

I have a column in my SQL server database named Total_Amount, I want to get the Sum(Total_Amount) for a specific day for a specific Cashier.  I am able to get for specific cashier only but if I want to get using the WHERE clause for both cashier AND date, it returns nothing.  The command works well in SQL server Management Studio but from the VB. nET,  it does not.

The below is my code.

```
         Dim conn As New SqlConnection("data. 
         source=PRECIOUSMUM\MSSQLSERVER_1; initial.    
         catalog=inventory; user id=mantics; 
         password=emudeji;")
        Try
        'Dim Total_Amountss As Double
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand
        With cmd

            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "SELECT   SUM(Total_Amount) 
          AS Total_Amount FROM tblOrder WHERE.    
        (cashier=@cashier) AND (Order_date=@Order_date)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier", 
         lbl_Cashier_Name.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_date", Date.Today.ToString)
            '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", dtpicker.Value.Date)

        End With

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        If IsDBNull(dr("Total_Amount")) Then
            lbl_cashier_Totalsales.Text = "N0.00"
        Else
            Dim str As Double
            str = dr.Item("Total_Amount")
            lbl_cashier_Totalsales.Text = FormatCurrency(dr.Item("Total_Amount"))
        End If
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Larnu,  what should I use instead of AddwithValue to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: The article covers that, @uthubaba . What part did you not understand and I'll be happy to try and explain, but it is quite explicit on what syntax you should use instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that it is clearly wrong is the fact that you use a string to query a Date column. This is never correct because the string is something that you use to display the date to your end users. It is not how the database (or .NET) stores the date value. So, a Date column is not queried using a string but passing directly the C# DateTime value in the Add method and specifying the DataType of the parameter.
A second possible error is caused by the fact that if you have also stored the Time part then passing a Date like Today will never match any row but only the ones that have 00:00:00 as their time value.

You need to query for >= midnight of the starting date and < of the following day.

This considerations will give a query like this:

```
With cmd
   .Connection = conn
   .CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Total_Amount) AS Total_Amount 
                   FROM tblOrder 
                   WHERE (cashier=@cashier) AND 
                   (Order_date >= @StartDate AND 
                    Order_date < @EndDate)"
   .Parameters.Add("@cashier", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lbl_Cashier_Name.Text
   .Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Today
   .Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Today.AddDays(1)
End With
```

Comment: It is still not working.  Funny enough,  I have done this type of SQL command on another software I did recently. I have rebuild the solution to no avail

Comment: Still not getting any result? What are the datatypes for the columns involved in the WHERE statement?

Comment: By the way _dr.Read_ returns a boolean to tell you if there are records to read. Get that value and check if it is true or not

Comment: Cashier is NvarChar. Order_date is Date and Total_Amount is Money.

Comment: Possibility of case mismatch? Use LIKE instead of = for cashier check.

Comment: If I use the Where (cashier=@cashier)  only,  it brings result.  If I use Where(order_date=@order_date) it brings results too. But when the AND is introduced to use the two conditions,  issues arises

Comment: Sounds like you don't hav any rows, for that cashier on that date then. Just because a `WHERE` brings back rows for each condition on its own doesn't mean it will when you use an `AND`.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu,  it is fine now.  The issue was the cashier name.  The cashier name is brought forward from the main menu form where the cashier logged on.  So seems like not seeing the cashier name but I have found a way around it.  Thanks boss